# What the best way to consistently get updates from Server in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, server-push

I am trying to develop an application which displays a game commentary. As you can guess the data gets updated every minute.

I am thinking of using the Push Notifications (APNS/GCM) to notify app of data change and the app will pull down latest data from the server.

But is that the best approach to move forward, should I be considering any other mechanisms? I came across few like

- Web Socket
- Http Streaming
- Http Long Polling

I am not familiar with the above-mentioned concepts. But would like to know the best approach in my scenario.

Thanks

Comment: not enough info about your backend, but Firebase can make the job easier

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using Push Notifications for that kind of function.

Push Notifications are meant more for marketing or alerting the *user* of some event - not the backend system. Besides, users can opt out of Push Notifications and could inadvertently break your app because of it.

I have had success with using WebSockets as a way to achieve this. They are pretty straightforward to setup a server to send and receive webhooks (I have used them for NodeJS so [here](https://socket.io/) is a link for that - but I am sure there are many similar packages for other languages.

Here is an [example library](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets) (I am sure there are others as well) that you can use to connect from your app to your backend server.

Hope this helps steer you in the right direction ;)

EDIT: Also just saw you are looking for iOS stuff too, so here is a [SocketIO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) library for iOS